# Thrift 0.9.0 not generating python code on ubuntu 14

Tags: python, ubuntu, hbase, thrift, ambari

Using Ambari 2.2.2.0 (HDP 2.4.2.0-258), which contains HBASE 1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.

Updating a python client developed for an earlier version of HBase.

Using Thrift 0.9.0, Neither `hbase1.thrift` or `hbase2.thrift` generate the `gen-py` directories (or anything) for python:

```
hadoop1:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/include/thrift$ thrift -verbose --gen py /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/include/thrift/hbase2.thrift 
Scanning /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/include/thrift/hbase2.thrift for includes
Parsing /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/include/thrift/hbase2.thrift for types
Program: /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/include/thrift/hbase2.thrift
Generating "py"
```

I have python 2.7.6 installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Credit to Josh Elser @ Hortonworks for solution ...  the user has to have permission to create a directory in "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/include/thrift".  Switching to a directory which is writable by user and re-runing the command solved the problem.